# Embulk to GCS: How to change output filename?

Tags: java, json, google-cloud-storage

As the title says, right now I can only set the path_prefix in yml config file but for example when I set path_prefix to embulk/test. The output filename on GCS is test.000.01.csv.

How can I change it so that the output is only test.csv or even test_timestamp.csv instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just needed to set the "sequence_format" value in yml config file to empty like this

```
out:
  type: gcs
  bucket: test
  path_prefix: embulk/test
  sequence_format: ""
  ....
```